# SQL how to display the value that appears more than once just once

Tags: sql, database

Example: If I have a table called "list" and have more columns like (id, game and genre) and I want to display a list of all the genres that games have and if a genre appears more than once I want to display it just once. (Need the SQL code) I've tried with `COUNT` but it doesn't work.

Example Table list:

[image]

Comment: Hi, your question isn't  well asked: take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Comment: Hey @bogdanpaul2000000 - Can you please provide what you've tried so far using `count` which is not working for your. Those details will be very helpful for the the community members who're trying to help you.

Comment: You should normalize your database. Gendre should be in separate table.

Answer (score 1):

try to use "distinct in sql"

list -> your table name
genre -> the column you wish to work on

```
SELECT DISTINCT genre FROM list;
```

Comment: gendre is a column, not a table, you can not select from it

Comment: @AntonínLejsek thank you, didnt realise the mistake. edited

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT *` will not work here, you need `DISTINCT` only :

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.genre
FROM list l;
```

`*`denotes all columns & in your sample data all columns data are not same.

So, you need only columns that are duplicate & need to show in `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using COUNT(), which you have tried, but 'did not work':

```
SELECT genre
FROM list 
GROUP BY genre
HAVING count(*)>0
```